# Transpile ES6 library nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to run a piece of node code that relies on a library that is using the new import syntax from ES6, [Girder](https://github.com/girder/girder). It fails with `Unexpected identifed`errors. So, I transpiled my source and that node module using Babel with the help of webpack. However, the babel-loader does not respect the test variable (only js files) resulting in the compilation errors.

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "oncofinder_web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "^1.3.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "girder": "^2.5.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p",
    "watch": "webpack --watch"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const config = {

  target: 'node',

  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client'),

  entry: {
    app: './app.js'
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: './bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.m?js$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
        }
      ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'])
  ],
}

module.exports = config;
```

Is there any way to use the Girder library with or without transpilation?

Regards

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: @Matt Kuhns 10.11.0

Comment: try using: node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs